# powershell remove last 3 characters from file name

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I need to recursively rename a bunch of files with the extension '.cop' (for copy) and get rid of that '.cop' string.

I made the following command from what I read on the `get-help rename-item` topic:

```
gci -r -i *.cop | Rename-Item -newname {$_.name -replace '\.cop',''}
```

but I get an IO exception error :

```
Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
```

PowerShell doesn't want to rename the file because it already exists? 
that doesn't make sense... anybody knows what I am doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Foreach-Object Cmdlet:

```
gci -r -i *.cop | % {ren $_ -newname $_.Name.Replace(".cop", "") -whatif}
```

Comment: Nice one Chris thanks very much. 
One last question, out of curiosity, can someone explain the use of $_.Name.Replace ? What is it ? some sort of variable-command ? How powershell names these ? Where can I find a list that shows all the possible variables (or whatever it's called)? Cheers

Comment: PowerShell - Special Characters And Tokens - http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens

Comment: Thanks Chris but that's not exactly what I meant. I knew about the dots I am not just not familiar with the syntax $_.var.command like $_.Name.Replace and wanted to see if there's a list of 'commands' that you can 'attach' to a var just like you did with $_.Name.Replace.

Comment: @Chris, foreach is not necessary, rename-item should accept objects from the pipeline.

Comment: $_ is a variable that refers to a FileSystemInfo object returned by Get-ChildItem. Like most objects, it has properties, one of which string type property called 'Name', which is also an object. It too has methods and properties, one of which is Replace(). To discover all the possible 'commands', you need to discover which object is being returned, FileSystemInfo, String, Int32, etc. then lookup that object's members on MSDN.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo_members(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're code works for me. Make sure you don't have a directory with the name of the file being renamed.